# jQuery Mobile Secure Pages

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm developing a jquery mobile site that is only available to users that are logged in.

I have a function that checks a server for their logged in status:

```
function checkLogin() {
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON(root_url + 'manageUsers/checklogin/?callback=?', null,
            function (data) {
                if (data.logged == 'false') {
                    $("#index_Container").html("<h2>Login Required</h2></div><p>We've noticed you're not logged in, please login to use this app.</p><p><a href='login.html' data-role='button'>Click here to login</a></p>").trigger('create');
                    $.mobile.changePage('login.html');
                } else {
                    $(".logged_in").text(data.username);
                    $(".logged_in").addClass('logout');
                    $(".header_div").trigger('create');
                }
            });
    });
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to implement this so everytime the index page is loaded and any other page loads this is fired prior to rendering anything else on the page. Currently, the page will load and show the HTML, then do $.mobile.changePage('login.html'):

**EDIT: If anyone has any ideas on how to implement this in a better way I'd love to know, every page in the app requires the user to be logged in.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have this function run every time you load anew page, you will need to bind it to the `pagebeforeload` event, and potentially cancel the user navigation if it does not validate the login.

```
$( document ).bind( "pagebeforeshow", function( event, data ){
  event.preventDefault(); //prevents usual load of page
  checkLogin(data);
});
```

You will have to make changes to checkLogin, notably because as the page does not exist yet, so you cannot make changes to the DOM. You can see an quick and dirty example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpn9G/3/), giving hints as to how do it considering the asynchronous nature of your call.

Comment: Am I able to just load the login page rather then insert the text? - Also does this work for the initial "index.html" page?

Comment: the problem I'm having is if I call event.preventDefault() inside a $.getJSON call, the page still renders then forwards.. not sure how to fix that.

Comment: you answered the question but still stuck on the json call. Thanks.